# Regex for file names with specific extensions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, filenames

I am trying to get a regex to match certain file names with specific extensions.

I have a log file in which I need to find file paths with specific extensions.

I slurp the entire file and would now like to apply regex.

Log File:

```
/xyz/arb_path/abc.rb /xyz/arb_path/def.xml foo bar /xyz/arb_path/ghi.pl foo bar /xyz/arb_path/jkl.xml   /xyz/arb_path/mno.rb
foo bar '/xyz/arb_path/pqr.pl'
foo bar '/xyz/arb_path/stu.rb'
```

The regex should match all `*.rb` files or all `*.pl` files.

> /xyz/arb_path/ghi.pl
>       /xyz/arb_path/pqr.pl

or

> /xyz/arb_path/abc.rb
>      /xyz/arb_path/mno.rb
>      /xyz/arb_path/stu.rb

Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice if you accepted one of the answers :)

Comment: Please provide a sample of how the filenames appear in the log file. Are they at the end of lines or embedded in them?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
files = %w[/xyz/abc.pl /xyz/def.rb /xyz/ghi.pl /xyz/jkl.rb /xyz/mno.pl foo.rb bar.pl /xyz/foo.java ]
files.grep(%r[/xyz/.+\.(?:rb|pl)$])

=> ["/xyz/abc.pl", "/xyz/def.rb", "/xyz/ghi.pl", "/xyz/jkl.rb", "/xyz/mno.pl"]
```

If you don't care what the path is, use:

```
files.grep(%r[\.(?:rb|pl)$])
=> ["/xyz/abc.pl",
    "/xyz/def.rb",
    "/xyz/ghi.pl",
    "/xyz/jkl.rb",
    "/xyz/mno.pl",
    "foo.rb",
    "bar.pl"]
```

You say the filenames being matched are in log files, but don't show an example of the file format. If the filenames are at the end of lines then the `$` anchor will pick up the matches. If the filenames are embedded in lines then remove the `$` anchor.

---

> This does not work for file paths with white space :(

Without modifications to the last example code, only adding some filenames with embedded spaces, and some paths with embedded spaces:

```
files = %w[/xyz/abc.pl /xyz/def.rb /xyz/ghi.pl /xyz/jkl.rb /xyz/mno.pl foo.rb bar.pl /xyz/foo.java ]
files += [
  'ruby file.rb',
  'perl file.pl',
  '/foo bar/ruby.rb',
  '/foo bar/perl.rb'
]

files.grep(%r[\.(?:rb|pl)$])
```

Looks like this in IRB:

```
irb(main):008:0> files = %w[/xyz/abc.pl /xyz/def.rb /xyz/ghi.pl /xyz/jkl.rb /xyz/mno.pl foo.rb bar.pl /xyz/foo.java ]
[
    [0] "/xyz/abc.pl",
    [1] "/xyz/def.rb",
    [2] "/xyz/ghi.pl",
    [3] "/xyz/jkl.rb",
    [4] "/xyz/mno.pl",
    [5] "foo.rb",
    [6] "bar.pl",
    [7] "/xyz/foo.java"
]
irb(main):009:0> files += [
irb(main):010:1*   'ruby file.rb',
irb(main):011:1*   'perl file.pl',
irb(main):012:1*   '/foo bar/ruby.rb',
irb(main):013:1*   '/foo bar/perl.rb'
irb(main):014:1> ]
[
    [ 0] "/xyz/abc.pl",
    [ 1] "/xyz/def.rb",
    [ 2] "/xyz/ghi.pl",
    [ 3] "/xyz/jkl.rb",
    [ 4] "/xyz/mno.pl",
    [ 5] "foo.rb",
    [ 6] "bar.pl",
    [ 7] "/xyz/foo.java",
    [ 8] "ruby file.rb",
    [ 9] "perl file.pl",
    [10] "/foo bar/ruby.rb",
    [11] "/foo bar/perl.rb"
]
irb(main):015:0> 
irb(main):016:0* files.grep(%r[\.(?:rb|pl)$])
[
    [ 0] "/xyz/abc.pl",
    [ 1] "/xyz/def.rb",
    [ 2] "/xyz/ghi.pl",
    [ 3] "/xyz/jkl.rb",
    [ 4] "/xyz/mno.pl",
    [ 5] "foo.rb",
    [ 6] "bar.pl",
    [ 7] "ruby file.rb",
    [ 8] "perl file.pl",
    [ 9] "/foo bar/ruby.rb",
    [10] "/foo bar/perl.rb"
]
```

So, yes, embedded whitespace is handled also.

---

```
'/xyz/arb_path/abc.rb /xyz/arb_path/def.xml foo bar /xyz/arb_path/ghi.pl foo bar /xyz/arb_path/jkl.xml   /xyz/arb_path/mno.rb'.split.grep(/\.(?:rb|pl)$/)
=> [
    [0] "/xyz/arb_path/abc.rb",
    [1] "/xyz/arb_path/ghi.pl",
    [2] "/xyz/arb_path/mno.rb"
]
```

Comment: This does not work for file paths with white space :(

Comment: Did you put that in your question as a requirement? And, see the additional code in my answer.

Comment: No, but a simpler answer would be `file.scan(\/xyz\/\S+\.(pl|rb)\b).flatten`.

Comment: That sample code doesn't even parse. Nor does it look like it'll match whitespace, unless it can occur before `/xyz/`. You're not defining where the white space can occur in your question.

Comment: Correction. `file.scan(/(\/xyz\/\S*\.(?:pl|rb)\b)/).flatten`, it does not look for white spaces within the file paths. The answer that you have requires an array and you conveniently inserted the elements with spaces. I require a log file to be searched, how should I turn that into an array?

Comment: Do you have an accurate example of your log file format in your question? You've changed the question seven times and altered the format of the filenames. That's a moving target and until it's stable we can't give you any valid answers. Scanning filenames is easy line-by-line. Trying to find them with embedded whitespace when they're on one line with no other delimiters makes it very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you

```
/\.(?:rb|pl)$/i
```

[examples](http://rubular.com/r/bA7KYAw7FO)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you just *.rb:

```
(\/xyz\/[\w\.\-_\s]+\.rb\b)
```

This will give you just *.pl:

```
(\/xyz\/[\w\.\-_\s]+\.pl\b)
```

This will give you both:

```
(\/xyz\/[\w\.\-_\s]+\.(pl|rb)\b)
```

Comment: Be careful with `\w+`. A filename can contain characters that aren't matched by `\w`, causing this to fail.

Comment: also, this will match an extension such as `.plds` or `.rbexe`

Comment: I tried something similar: `(\/xyz\/\S+\.rb)` but spaces can exist in the names.

Comment: Noted - thanks for the feedback.  Added word boundary following extension and expanded character set that will match in filename.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(\/xyz\/.*\.(?:rb|pl))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
pattern = /(\/\w+)+.pl/
```

this will match all pl extensions

change *.pl* to *.rb* to match .rb extensions

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution to a similar problem I came across in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "/xyz/abc.pl /xyz/def.rb /xyz/ghi.pl /xyz/jkl.rb /xyz/mno.pl /xyz/ab c.pl /xyz/d ef.rb /xyz/g hi.pl /xyz/jk l.rb /xyz/mn o.pl  /xyz/abc.pli /xyz/def.rbexe /xyz/ghi.pli /xyz/jkl.rbexe /xyz/mno.pli";
my @matches = min_match ($string, '/xyz/', '.pl');
for (@matches) {
    print $_ . "\n";
}

sub min_match {
    my ($string, $start, $end) = @_;

    my $reversed_string = reverse $string;
    my $pattern = '\b' . reverse ($end) . '.*?' . reverse ($start);
    my @matches = ();
    my $continue = 1;

    while ($continue) {
        $continue = 0;
        if ($reversed_string =~ /$pattern/) {
            my $match = reverse $&;
            $reversed_string =~ s/$pattern//;
            push @matches, $match;
            $continue = 1;
        }
    }
    return @matches;
}
```

Output:

> /xyz/mn o.pl
>       /xyz/g hi.pl
>       /xyz/ab c.pl
>       /xyz/mno.pl
>       /xyz/ghi.pl
>       /xyz/abc.pl